# Force Thunderbird to send email with font size 11pt

Tags: email, thunderbird, fonts

I have used Outlook 2013 until today, when I finally decided to stop using it until they decide to fix all its IMAP problems. I have therefore reverted to using Thunderbird for now, but there is one thing that I still can't get right.

I think that Outlook's default font and font size look perfect (Calibri 11pt), they look good on every email client. Unfortunately, Thunderbird only allows to choose between small, medium etc font sizes when sending emails, and it looks like the "medium" setting (which should mean that the font size is actually not set, and will depend on the settings on the person who receives the message), doesn't seem to work as intended, meaning that the receiver sees it with a bigger font size than their default.

So, is there a way to force Thunderbird to send emails with a specific font size?

Comment: What format is the mail you're sending?  IE: Plain-text doesn't keep formatting rules in the email.

Comment: @techie007 I always send it as HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first thought was to use a signature but that a pain because of the extra line before the signature.

Then i found an extension [ExternalTemplateLoader](https://nic-nac-project.org/~kaosmos/templateloader-en.html) where you can specify a html-file with your font-specifications. (and also background color etc.) Under `Tools/ExternalTemplateLoader options` you can specify when (and which) template you want loaded as default. (also if you want the template when replying)

You can use the following html-code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body style="font-face: Calibri, Verdana; font-color:black; font-size: 11pt;">
</body>
</html>
```

I don't know if you want 11px or 11pt but you can try.

Comment: Unfortunately, ExternalTemplateLoader is not compatible with Thunderbird 68+. Is there an alternative template add-on?

Comment: @Mateng From the comments of the downloadpage of ExternalTemplateLoader: "If you need this functionality for Thunderbird 68, try the SmartTemplate4 Add-on, which now also includes similar functionality to the also abandoned Stationery Add-on."

Comment: Link to SmartTemplate4 for TB 74-78: https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/smarttemplate4/     Link for TB 68: https://addons.thunderbird.net/en-US/thunderbird/addon/smarttemplate4/versions/?page=1#version-2.14.4

Answer (score 2):

You could use Html commands to specify the size. Go `Insert` - `HTML`.
Create a div Html element as the following:

```
<div style="font-size: 11pt;">
  Foo
  Bar
  Bazz
</div>
```

[image]

More info in [`Default HTML font for new messages`](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Default_HTML_font_for_new_messages_%28Thunderbird%29).

Comment: Thanks for this. However, do yow know if there is a way to have this automatically done for every new message and reply? Unfortunately it looks like there is no HTML Options menu in the Composition menu anymore...

Comment: Of if you specify it as a html-signature you wouldn't have to do that insert every time.

Comment: In version 17.0.8 the HTML option is still under Insert.

Comment: @Rik HTML is still under Insert, HTML Options is not in the Composition menu anymore. Also, could you explain what you meant about using an HTML signature?

Comment: You mean the option in `Tools/Options/Composition` ? I have never seen an option there to send HTML-mail. The option for default plain-text or HTML can be found under `Account Settings/Composition and Addressing`.

Comment: For the HTML signature: you can under `Account settings/Composition and Addressing` give a HTML signature. For instance `<font color=black size=25pt>text<br>--<br>Regards,<br>Name<br>etc.<br></font>`. You can then type over "text" in your font. But it has some drawbacks. You need to remove the default -- in the settings and you always have a blank line which you can't get rid of easily without messing up your font. However, you can use it for a normal HTML-signature. The solution stated by me using ExternalTemplateLoader is a much better and stable one. Also with replies.